# How to do Binary Trees?

Tags: tree, binary-tree

How do I start this off?

Your program should begin by prompting the user for a filename. Then, open that
file and use it as necessary to do the following: Use a binary search tree that stores at each node
both a string and a count of how many of that node it has found. Then, go through the file given
(text file) and starting with the first letter, put it onto the tree with a count of 1. Then get the next
character in the file, push it onto the tree, and so forth. If you ever try to add a node that has
already been added (for example, pushing an ‘a’ onto the tree that already has an ‘a’, increment
the count at that node.
Once that is done, go through the file again and get all consecutive 2-letter occurrences
and push them onto the tree. Again, if there is a match, increment the count.
Repeat this entire process until you reach a ‘k’ long sequence.

Comment: Ask a CS student for help?

Comment: Reading a book about trees and programming would be good. Bothering us with your homework would not be considered a good way to start. Especially as your lecturer will probably see this and be rather angry with the approach.

Comment: What's the point of doing this homework if you don't even know what you are doing?

Comment: Is anyone going to actually help me start it off? I'm not asking you to do it obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I will not do any coding ( because you said nothing about language etc.). But I think I can help you with this. I'll just asume C++ and that you know basics of that language.

> Your program should begin by prompting the user for a filename.

This is pretty easy (just some cin ).

> Then, open that file

Again just language implementation - just use fstream to read file.

> Use a binary search tree that stores at each node both a string and a count of how many of that node it has found

Try to implement BST as written [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/) but store in each node some int which is counter of a repetition of value and value as char*.

> Then, go through the file given

Now scan stream char by char(then 2chars,3chars,...kchars) and use tree.add(char*) on them.

Your tree should look something like this :

```
class Tree{
   Node * head;
   void Add(char*);
};
```

And your node :

```
class Node{
   char* data;
   Node* right;
   Node* left;
   int counter;
};
```

And here is 'pseudocode' of program :

1. Read file name (string name) and (int k)
2. Open file F = open(name)
3. Open stream S(F), int i = 1, Init Tree T
4. while(i<=k)

   1. read S from k = 0 to k == end

      1. read i characters char* chars
      2. T.add(chars)
      3. k+=i
   2. i++

Comment: It's C++. Thanks. Could we talk more in PM?

Comment: I'd prefer if you could rewrite your question or start a new one.
You can post any of your code or certain questions about BSTs - this would be much helpfull